# How to handle multi-channel matrix

Tags: opencv

I have a 500x500 Mat object (green plane of an image).
I have created a 500x500x3 (where 3 is the number of channels) zero Mat object.
Is there an openCV 2.4.3 function to copy the green plane in the second channel of the new "zero" Mat object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process 1:

```
int from_to[] = {0,1}
mixChannels(Green_plane,1,Created_mat,3,from_to,1);
```

[Explanation of the above](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mixchannels)

Process 2 (lil lengthy..)

```
Mat Green_plane;//you already have this matrix as the green plane of an image

//create a 3 channeled matrix with all entries set to zero
Mat Created_mat = Mat::zeros(rows,cols,CV_8UC3);

//its a vector array of images that will contain the 3 planes of the above 3 channeled   matrix
vector<Mat> bgr_plane;

// divide the 3 channeled matrix into 3 one channeled matrix
split(Created_mat,bgr_plane);

// take the green plane, which is the middle matrix out of the 3 matrices contained in the vector array bgr_planes, and copy your already given green matrix to it
bgr_plane[1] = Green_plane.clone();

//merge the vector of one channeled matrices into a 3 channeled matrix
merge(bgr_plane,Created_mat);//EDITED

// now Created_mat has the green channel same as given green matrix you already have (Green_plane) and the rest 2 planes are still set to zero
```

**EDIT...FOR 4 CHANNEL..**

```
vector<Mat> each_channel;
split(Mat_4_channel,each_channel);

//accessing each pixel of each channel
each_channel[0].at<uchar>(row,col);//1st channel
each_channel[1].at<uchar>(row,col);//2nd channel
each_channel[2].at<uchar>(row,col);//3rd channel
each_channel[3].at<uchar>(row,col);//4th channel
```

Comment: Could you explain what your code actually do function by function? Thank you very much

Comment: Great! the only problem I have is that "merge" is underlined as an error (overload). What do you think about?

Comment: ok...there was an error in the first code, you must swap into merge merge. Now it's ok, thanks a lot

Comment: Now I have another problem: how can I access this at pixel level the Created_mat??? something like this: ACreated_mat.at<Vec3b>(ii,jj)[k];

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html#accessing-pixel-intensity-values

Comment: I'd like to know this: if created_mat (to access) have more than 3 planes, how can I access at pixel level?? I can't use it: Vec3f intensity = img.at<Vec3f>(y, x);
float blue = intensity.val[0];
float green = intensity.val[1];
float red = intensity.val[2];

Answer (score 0):

```
void mixChannels(const vector<Mat>& srcv, vector<Mat>& dstv, const int* fromTo, int npairs)
```

more information about this function can be found at: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#mixChannels